# Add field to existing django app in production environment

Tags: python, django, django-south, database-migration

I have an existing django app and would like to add a field to a model.
But because the website is already in production, just deleting the database is not an option any more.

These are the steps I took:

- `pip install south`
- added 'south' to INSTALLED_APPS
- `python manage.py syncdb`
- `python manage.py convert_to_south [myapp]`

So now I have the initial migration and south will recognize the changes. Then I added the field to my model and ran:

- `python manage.py schemamigration [myapp] --auto`
- `python manage.py migrate [myapp]`

Now I have the following migrations:

- 0001_initial.py
- 0002_auto__add_field_myapp_fieldname.py

Which commands should I run on my production server now to migrate? Also should I install south first and then pull the code changes and migrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first is to fake the initial migration:

`python manage.py migrate [yourapp] --fake 0001`

then you can apply the migration to the db

`python manage.py migrate [yourapp]`

---

I'm assuming you ran `convert_to_south` on development, in which case production still wouldn't be aware of the migrations yet.  `convert_to_south` automatically fakes the initial migration for you!  If you were to just run `migrate` on production without faking, it should error.